# Angular2 create a list from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Using Angular2 I'm trying to make a list from an array...something like:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="">
                {{names}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    `,
})
export class AppComponent {

    names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

}
```

How can I get something like this to work?

Comment: Did you really have this problem?  I would think [any documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor) with NgFor would demonstrate how to do this.  I.e., I think it would take you longer to post this question then it would to find the answer with a simple Internet search. Questions are supposed to show some research effort.  Obviously you know that something like `#ngFor=""` isn't going to work.  You should show what you tried, and where you got stuck, or why you couldn't figure this out based on some documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#name of names">
                {{name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    `,
})

export class AppComponent {

    names = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];

}
```

Comment: I'm getting name1,name2,name3 in each line so 3 times name1,name2,name3 ... how can I get it to just show 1 name for each line?

Comment: You most likely typod in your code, putting {{names}} instead of {{name}}, as per the example in the plnkr i posted above.

Comment: @MSwehli I did originally but I quickly corrected it :)

Comment: @RichardVanbergen didn't actually notice you did too, but i meant that aboutn Satch3000's code so i guess thats where the original issue started :)

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for Angular Framework v2's syntax - not AngularJS v2 like me here it is:

```
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let name of names;">
                {{name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Not saying anyone did anything wrong in the question or anything, their versioning and angular v.s. older angularjs is confusing IMO